# Applying Hanning window to my echo signal in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have some troubles with something in Matlab, I am processing my echo signal in order to do the Delay and Sum procedure but unfortunately I am no quite sure how to implement the Hanning window to my signal. I know that in Matlab I have the function "hann", but I am no familiarize how to use it.

I will provide some parameters

```
f = 40 KHz my signal captured
Fs = 20e6 frecuency sampled
A = 65536 samples X axis of my eco captured
my signal amplitude vary
```

this is one type of signal that I want to apply hann window

[image: signal pic]
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should create your hanning window using the function you said ("hann"):

```
window = hann(A);
```

where `A` is the length of the window, and the length of your signal (65536 in your example). Then you should multiply element-by-element your signal and the window:

```
windowed_signal = window.*your_signal;
```